# Python mysql.connector - Correct way to retrive a row as dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I've a table with 20 columns, I use this code to get every field of a specific movie as a dictionary:

```
import mysql.connector

def getMovie(id):
   movie = {}
   cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   query = ('SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id = %s') % id
   cursor.execute(query)
   for row in cursor:
      movie['id'] = row[0]
      movie['actors'] = row[1]
      movie['title'] = row[2]
      # and so on for 20 lines
    return movie
```

Column names would be the dictionary keys. Is there a shorter way to archive the same result? 20 lines of variables are really bad looking....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass `dictionary=True` to the cursor to get it to return a dictionary.

```
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

See the [docs on MySQLCursorDict](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `zip` to club your attribute names and values as:

```
attribute_names = ["id", "actors", "title"]
values = [10, 20, 30] # row in your case
d = dict(zip(attribute_names, values))
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

does not work anymore, we have to pass the class DictCursor as parameter of cnx.cursor

```
cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```